# gensim LdaMulticore can't work on cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, gensim, lda

I want to use gensim LDA module on cloud function, but it time out and show "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/past/builtins/misc.py:45: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses".

But the same code worked on colab (python 3.8.16) and I did't find any bug in it.
It can print 'LDA1' and 'LDA2', then time out.

```
def LDA(corpus, dictionary, NumTopic):
    print('LDA1')
    time1 = time.time()
    print('LDA2')
    lda = gensim.models.LdaMulticore(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=NumTopic,  chunksize=1000, iterations=200, passes=20, per_word_topics=False,  random_state=100)
    print('LDA3')
    corpus_lda = lda[corpus] 
    print("LDA takes %2.2f seconds." % (time.time() - time1))
    return lda, corpus_lda
```

1.I have tried diffierent python version like 3.10, 3.8, 3.7

2.ADD import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)

3.It works on colab and 300 text just cost 10 sec, but I need it work on cloud function QQ

Comment: The `DeprecationWarning` is likely unrelated to the failure – but if it's appearing one place and not the other, may be indicative of some difference in Python/library versions that could bit you later. You should concentrate on one Python that you know works on Colab, and study/report closely on (a) the exact full error message, & exactly how long it takes to report back (isn't the cloud timeout at least 9 minutes?); (b) any other logged output/errors suggesting anything different than the Colab environment where it's working. You could add these details to your question.

Comment: Also: your code fragment doesn't show where things like `corpus` come from, so how exactly the cloud-function will do eveything needed for the code to run is unclear. And, is an LDA operation of only 300 texts, running for merely 10 seconds, the real training you need to do? (That sounds atypically tiny.)